# Variable from Kotlin class returning it's default value over the modified one

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Im using a java and a kotlin class on my program. Java class is supposed to recieve a String value after it is edited in a function but it always bring back the default value. I've  been working on it for over 4 hours at this point I think and I lost it. Hopefully you guys can help me with this. I've posted the code on the following link:

https://pastebin.com/wiQn8P6S

Dont wanna clutter the post too much with unencessary codes so I cut it a bit. At the moment `WeatherDescription` always becomes equal to `""` instead of the value it is assigned in `getTemp()`. I've been working on why and how the variable's value gets resetted back to `""` or if it's ever set to any meaningful String at all. I see sometimes its getting the intended String value on debug and it gets wiped afterwards I think somehow.

Comment: Please edit your question to put all the code that is pertitent to your problem in the question itself, do not link to code that is hosted somewhere else. You can follow these [guidelines to produce a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o

Answer (score 0):

The way you're obtaining weather data is asynchronous. By the time you `call WeatherDescription = weatherData.gettDesc();` the weather information might not have been retrieved yet. You can solve this by using LiveData to observe the response when it's received.

Update:
In WeatherData.kt define liveData like this

```
val desc = MutableLiveData<String>()
val icon = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

then at the end of getTemp post your received values

```
desc.postValue(locationName + "\n" + weatherDescription)
icon.postValue("https:" + weatherIcon)
```

Now in MainActivity.java you can observe for changes and update UI accordingly:

```
weatherData.desc.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(String s) {
    }
});

    weatherData.icon.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way I can make sure the info is definetly recieved then continue the program?

Comment: I updated my answer to further explain how to collect your data.